# hierarchyviewer not working

Tags: android, sdk, adb, hierarchyviewer

When I run hierarchyviewer I am getting warning

`SWT folder '/home/sharanu/work/android-ics-source/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/swt/swt.jar' does not exist.
Please export ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.`

then I tried after setting `ANDROID_SWT` still the same error. But earlier `hierarchyviewer` was working fine. I am not sure why its not working now.

Please see the Image.[image]

Comment: What is your SDK version ?

Comment: @Saurabh Bayani earlier I had 20, now I updated to SDK 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just deleted the `ANDROID_SWT` variable from `~/.bashrc` and it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue.
I made ANDROID_SWT point to swt.jar located in the android sdk folder and it worked started working.

Steps:

i)
Find the location of swt.jar.
In your SDK folder, perform a

```
find . -name swt.jar
```

ii)
And export its path in environment variable ANDROID_SWT.

```
export ANDROID_SWT= <path from step 1>
```

In my case, the following worked:

```
export ANDROID_SWT=${ANDROID_SDK}/tools/lib/x86_64/
```